# jquery switch click class picture change

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<tab>
<div class="switchLeft"></div>


.switchLeft
{

}

.switchRight
{

}



js code

 $("div.switchLeft").click(function () {

          if (className == "switchRight") {
            $(this).removeClass("switchRight");
            $(this).addClass("switchLeft");

        }

        else if (className == "switchLeft") {
            $(this).removeClass("switchRight");
            $(this).addClass("switchRight");
            break;

        }

    });
```

but   else if here in after,switch is working again and switchRight removing
 thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access class you can use `this.className`  or it should be `$(this).attr('class')`

```
if($(this).attr('class') == "switchRight") {

    $(this).removeClass("switchRight");
    $(this).addClass("switchLeft");

}

else if ($(this).attr('class') == "switchLeft") {
    $(this).removeClass("switchLeft");
    $(this).addClass("switchRight");
    break;

}
```

With this.className

```
if(this.className == "switchRight") {

    $(this).removeClass("switchRight");
    $(this).addClass("switchLeft");

}

else if (this.className == "switchLeft") {
    $(this).removeClass("switchLeft");
    $(this).addClass("switchRight");
    break;

}
```

Comment: thank you but not working because  have two class name plase your look here http://b1207.hizliresim.com/z/v/b4tlp.jpg

Comment: There was problem in switchLeft as you were remove switchRight class in else where it has swithLeft class which could not be removed. I have updated my answer check if it works.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
 $(this).removeClass("switchRight");
 $(this).addClass("switchRight");
```

I suspect you want

```
 $(this).removeClass("switchLeft");
 $(this).addClass("switchRight");
```

otherwise your just adding and removing the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("div").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("switchLeft switchRight");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S4WG3/

**Note:** one of the reasons your code is not switching every time is because of your original selector.  `$("div.switchLeft")` will only pull `div`s with the class `switchLeft`, so `div`s with `switchRight` will never switch back.

Comment: hello thank you..my this code working..http://jsfiddle.net/S4WG3/1/ but not working in the project.. why ? http://depositfiles.com/rmv/4217531069855586

Comment: I can't access your site, unfortunately, because I'm behind a pretty strong filter.  Could you update your original post and paste your new code below your original question?